# mongoDB, PHP update specific value not all the values

Tags: php, mongodb

I am having a problem in updating values i get from web service ..

```
 $collection = $modb->$table;
    $collection->update(array("id" => (int)$row['id']),
    array('$set' => array(
    "user_id" => (int)$post_data_array['user_id'],
    "story" => (int)$post_data_array['story'],
    "surprize_sub1" => (int)$post_data_array['surprize_sub1'],
    "surprize_sub2" => (int)$post_data_array['surprize_sub2'],
    "surprize_sub3" => (int)$post_data_array['surprize_sub3'],
    "exr_solve" => (int)$post_data_array['exr_solve'],
    "exr_assessmnt" => (int)$post_data_array['exr_assessmnt'],
    "exr_refresh" => (int)$post_data_array['exr_refresh'],
    "sound_control" => (int)$post_data_array['sound_control'],
    "clock_control" => (int)$post_data_array['clock_control'],
    "switch_user" => (int)$post_data_array['switch_user'],
    "exr_print" => (int)$post_data_array['exr_print'],
    "write_on_wall" => (int)$post_data_array['write_on_wall'],
    "switch_letter" => (int)$post_data_array['switch_letter'],
    "view_controls" => (int)$post_data_array['view_controls'],
    )));
```

I get these values from end users.. i want the specific field sent to be updated without loosing all the rest of data ..

in this code only sent data is set while removing the rest .. i want to change only sent ones by keeping the rest as they are, please advice

Answer (score -1):

you need to use [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/crud/#update-one-document) instead of update .

> **updateOne**
>
> Use the MongoDB\Collection::updateOne() method to update a single document matching a filter.

```
$collection = $modb->$table;
$collection->updateOne(array("id" => (int)$row['id']),
array('$set' => array(
    // .... array elements
)));
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan how about if i have changed multiple ones, but not all the fields .. do you have any idea about it?

Comment: in your second array , only choose the fields that you want to update.

Comment: Hassan, since this is a webservice i cant guarantee which values were updated .. can you help me to check the values i got from the webservice and check them before updating the values in my mongoDB .. i am new to this!

Comment: since this is a webservice **YOU MUST** validate and guarantee the values that you are sending to your database

Comment: sure .. but how to do so?  .. i want to check the following : if i had a value replace the old one elsewise keep the old value .. and update the DB

Comment: filter your array out of your update operation, before you set it into updateOne